# UIwebview does not respond to touchesBegan

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, touch

I have subclass of UIViewController which has UIWebview as a subview added. 
I'm trying to detect touch events on webview but failing to do so.

`-(void)touchesBegan` 
is the method which should get called.

Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting touches on UIWebView is not trivial.

Check this tutorial : http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

BTW - If you need only to detect a touch on a links or buttons and add a custom action you can do it to. look here:

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tip-firing-custom-events-when-a-link-is-clicked-in-a-uiwebview/

Good Luck

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your UIWebView is the first responder.  When you add it, use [`becomeFirstResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder) on the web view (I've linked the documentation at Apple for you).

Also make sure `becomeFirstResponder` returns YES.

Lastly, make sure your view controller's UIView `userInteractionEnabled` property is set to YES.